# How to seed \FPseed with a value that is unique for every compilation?

Tags: random-numbers, fp

How to seed `\FPseed` with a value that is unique for every compilation? Is there a LaTeX macro to get the CPU tick so I can use it to seed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\FPseed\macroinquestiontoseed
\FPrandom\x
% x must produce different result for each compilation
\x%output
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you provide a small MWE?

Comment: Just don't set `\FPseed`

Comment: @egreg: Without a real time seed the output will be the same for each compilation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I want to produce a unique random number for each compilation. For example, today compilation I got 0.12345. Tomorrow compilation I will get a different value, for example .54321.

Comment: With `pdf(la)tex`, you can use `\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000`.

Comment: @mozartstraße The lack of documentation about `fp` is really impressive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `pdftex` (as engine) or `luatex`, you can use `\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\FPseed\expandafter=\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000\relax
\FPrandom\x
% x must produce different result for each compilation
\x%output
\end{document}
```

Without `pdftex` (as engine), as suggested by FP "documentation", you can use the following code (the seed changes *each minute*):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\FPseed=\the\time
\multiply\FPseed\the\day
\multiply\FPseed\the\month
\multiply\FPseed\the\year

\begin{document}
\FPrandom\x
% x must produce different result for each minute
\x%output
\end{document}
```

Comment: @mozartstraße Only `pdftex` has an internal clock with frequent ticks, but then `\pdfuniformdeviate` is better (and works also in `luatex`); `xetex` only has the same clock as original TeX, that knows only the time in minutes after midnight the job started. Of course you know that running `latex` uses `pdftex` as engine.